# Несколько адресов к статике в Nginx

Tags: nginx

Уважаемые, кто компетентен в настройках Nginx, подскажите.

Статика проекта лежит в одном месте, статика админки в другом, в Nginx прописал для статики проекта:

```
location /static {  
  autoindex on;  
  alias /home/user/project/apps/static;  
}
```

Статика проекта работает, но вот статика админки не пашет, как прописать второй адрес к сататике админки? Адрес такой: /home/user/django/Django-1.4.2/django/contrib/admin/static/

То есть второй путь прописать к location /static

Система django + nginx

На всякий случай настройки медиа в django:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/project/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/project/apps/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/home/user/project/apps/static/",
    "/home/user/django/Django-1.4.2/django/contrib/admin/static/",
)
```

В тестовом режиме все работает хорошо и правильно, так как там сам виртуальный сервер раздаёт статику по настройкам в settings, а вот на рабочем сервере, уже отдаёт статику nginx по этому и нужно его настроить так чтобы он по двум адресам смотрел статистику (Конечно если я все верно понимаю).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте manage collectstacic

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Объясню чуть детальнее.
STATIC_ROOT  - это не место где django ищет статику. Это место КУДА джанго свалит всю найденную статику после выполнения команды manage.py collectstatic. Collectstatic дефолтно проходится по всем источникам статики ВСЕХ приложенией в том числе django.contrib.admin и кладет их статику в STATIC_ROOT. app_name/static  - это одно из дефолтных месторасположений, т.е. ваша конфигурация STATICFILES_DIRS не нужна.

Таким образом надо делать так чтобы nginx маппил STATIC_URL на STATIC_ROOT, собственно что у вас и сделано. Но крайне желателельно выносить STATIC_ROOT за пределы каталогов с кодом проекта.

Таким образом процесс выкладки проекта помимо manage.py syncdb ( или migrate) должен включать в себя collectstatic чтобы доложить или обновить статику все приложений вашего проекта.

Обращаю на одну тонкость. collectstatic свалит все в одну кучу. Потому желательно организовывать статику приложения следующим образом. app_name/static/app_name и соответсвенно подключать в шаблонах как  {% static "app_name/my_static_resoure" %}  см код того же django.contrib.admin к примеру

PS актульная версия django 1.8 если вы только учитесь или не дорабатываете старый проект не тяните старье. Со времен 1.4 очень много изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что можно поставить несколько приватных локейшенов для этого:

```
location / { # Check app static
    alias /home/user/project/apps/static/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @admin_static;
}
location @admin_static { # Check admin static
    alias /home/user/django/Django-1.4.2/django/contrib/admin/static/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @django;
}
location @django { # If no static handle request by app
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```